# 2014 Hyundai Tucson cooling fan not running

Tags: ac, hyundai, relay, tucson

So our 2014 Hyundai Tucson (GDi) cooling fan doesn't seem to come on when it's hot or when the ac is on.  The ac only blows cold when the car is moving and the car sometimes overheats when idling.  I had a can of AC Pro on hand that has a pressure gauge on the low side.  The pressure read High when I connected the AC Pro and ran the AC so I DID NOT put any freon in.  That's also when I noticed that the fan was not running.

I looked at the C/FAN Hi relay and it did not have any corrosion on the terminals or heating.  The relay tests good both the solenoid and the switching.  There is power to the relay solenoid when the AC is running.  There is no power to the switched contacts for that relay.  The fan motor runs if I supply it power.

Any ideas of what I can check??

Is there a separate engine compartment condenser fan relay other than the relays listed on this diagram?

PS: The ac system is constantly cycling the compressor on 10 seconds off 30 seconds.

[image: Fuse box diagram]

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: If there's another relay in there which is like the hi/fan one, exchange it and see if it runs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ... I'll check it out @Paulster2

Comment: does the tucson have 2 fans or just 1?  the lo/hi relays are leading me to think its a 2 fan setup.  Just because the relay passes a visual inspection doesn't mean it actually works

Comment: The C/fan Relays Hi & lo are different amp rated relays so I can't swap them.  There is only one fan for the radiator and condenser combined.  I think I'll start a bounty.

Comment: You can always do one of two things to check the fan. First way is to pull the fan relay and jump the terminals with a wire. If it kicks in, the relay is bad. You might want to check the socket to ensure there's power to it. Secondly, you could also try pulling the wiring for the fan itself and supplying power directly. If it runs there, you know the fan is good. If it doesn't in either case, you have your culprit. You can also jump the relay directly to  ensure it is clicking, then check for continuity on the other side.

Comment: One thing to think about is if your car has a "factory debug mode".  I don't have experience with this car at all, but in some older cars there's a little plug that is supposed to stay unplugged because it enables this mode.  If you recently found a strange plug and plugged it in, you might try unplugging it.

Comment: Also, I assume your engine light is not on?  If you have any codes, you should post those as well.

Comment: No codes or light